# Iterator.next() return type in Java?

Tags: java, list, iterator, generic-programming

I am getting an error in the below code:

```
Class ABC{
  public <T extends Object> void process(Entity entity){
  List<T> list = entity.getList();
    Iterator<T> iterator = list.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        T currentItem = iterator.next();
        processCurrentItem();
    }
   }
}
```

The error when executing iterator.next():
**java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to Object**

My question, is the problem specific to my use case, or am I failing to understand how to utilize a hashmap and cast it to an object of my choice
?

Comment: Please include more code. I don't see any HashMap (or LinkedHashMap) in your code, and it's not clear where/how T is declared.

Comment: Please provide your complete error stacktrace.

Comment: @Eran the list I am using, is the list of T type objects, and an iterator over the list is returning a LinkedHashMap instead of an element of type T. Let me know if the edit doesn't help.

Comment: @jackjay I could find only the below error:
Could not export artifacts java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.__.__.Object

Comment: which line throws the exception?

Comment: It's at iterator.next() line, have edited the question with this detail as well.

Comment: Are you importing a class called `Object` somewhere?

Comment: The class Object has been imported in ABC to support the declaration over the process method. Have not made unnecessary imports elsewhere.

Comment: what about Entity? where is the import statement for that...plz comment the import of that

Comment: also once try using public <T extends Object,Entity>

Answer (score 0):

The problem (as clarified in the comments) is that there is an import of a class called `Object` that is not the default (`java.lang.Object`). Therefor `T extends Object` is interpreted as "a class that extends that custom `Object` class", and `java.util.LinkedHashMap` does not do that.

The solution would be to remove the import if you intended to use the default `java.lang.Object`. If you do need the custom `Object` class, you can instead change `<T extends Object>` to `<T extends java.lang.Object>`, or simply `<T>` since `extends java.lang.Object` is the default.

Comment: I got the point differentiating Object and java.lang.Object, but I got confused in the implementation of the solution for the given problem.
Do you mean to say that I can only use an object that is compatible with LinkedHashMap to catch the response from iterator.next() method call?

Comment: Another observation is : 
T currentItem = iterator.next(); --does not throw an error in the editor, but throws a runtime error, LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to Object.
On the other hand,
HashMap<K,V> map = iterator.next(); --throws an error before compilation, Cannot convert from T to HashMap.

Comment: I take it the imports were not the problem then? If so, I need to remove this answer. But yeah I meant that since T is bounded to your custom `Object` class, then your List and Iterator may only contain objects that extend that `Object` class and nothing else. Else you'll get the class cast exception as you have. Strange thing is I can't even compile your example without adding a cast to `List<T>`: https://ideone.com/dUb1Cu